# How to convert ISO-4217-Code to currency name in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a large dataset with various currencies. As for visualisation purpose I would like to display the full name of the currencies and not the ISO-4217-Code (currency code).

Let me take the following excerpt of the data:

```
# dataframe
id = rep(1:8)
country = c("USA", "Canada", "UK", "Switzerland", "USA", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Canada")
currency_code = c("USD", "CAD", "GBP", "CHF", "USD", "SEK", "CHF", "CAD")

df1 = data.frame(id, country, currency_code)
```

I could now with a left join manually assigning the currency name to the ISO-4217-Code which would work. But I'm looking personally for a more elegant way to do it than below shown:

```
country = c("USA", "Canada", "UK", "Switzerland", "Sweden")
currency_name = c("US Dollar", "Canadian Dollar", "Great Britain Pound", "Swiss franc", "Swedish krona")

df2 = data.frame(country, currency_name)

#left join
merge(df1, df2, by = "country", all.x = TRUE)
```

So my desired data would look like this

```
  country      id currency_code       currency_name
  Canada        2           CAD     Canadian Dollar
  Canada        8           CAD     Canadian Dollar
  Sweden        6           SEK       Swedish krona
  Switzerland   4           CHF         Swiss franc
  Switzerland   7           CHF         Swiss franc
  UK            3           GBP Great Britain Pound
  USA           1           USD           US Dollar
  USA           5           USD           US Dollar
```

With the [countrycode](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/countrycode/countrycode.pdf) package it is possible to assign country names to the country code (vice versa). Also it is possible to assign the currency code to a country, which is sadly not what my goal is.

I am aware that a left join would also give me a solution, but I would appreciate it if someone knows a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use the currency_list dataset from `currencycode` and join the 'currency_code' column with the input dataset 'df1'

```
library(dplyr)
# remotes::install_github("KKulma/currencycode")
library(currencycode)
data(currency_list)
currency_list %>%
   select(currency_code, currency_name) %>%
   filter(complete.cases(currency_code)) %>%
   right_join(df1)
```

-output

```
#    currency_code   currency_name id     country
#1           CAD Canadian Dollar  2      Canada
#2           CAD Canadian Dollar  8      Canada
#3           CHF     Swiss Franc  4 Switzerland
#4           CHF     Swiss Franc  7 Switzerland
#5           GBP  Pound Sterling  3          UK
#6           SEK   Swedish Krona  6      Sweden
#7           USD       US Dollar  1         USA
#8           USD       US Dollar  5         USA
```

Comment: that is really cool! I was not aware of the library(currencycode), which is really handy for this. Thx man! :)

Comment: Does currencycode seriously not feature Euro???

Answer (score 2):

The `countrycode` package also includes currency names...

```r
library(dplyr)
library(countrycode)

df1 %>% 
  mutate(currency_name = countrycode(country, "country.name", "currency"))
#>   id     country currency_code   currency_name
#> 1  1         USA           USD       US Dollar
#> 2  2      Canada           CAD Canadian Dollar
#> 3  3          UK           GBP  Pound Sterling
#> 4  4 Switzerland           CHF     Swiss Franc
#> 5  5         USA           USD       US Dollar
#> 6  6      Sweden           SEK   Swedish Krona
#> 7  7 Switzerland           CHF     Swiss Franc
#> 8  8      Canada           CAD Canadian Dollar
```

---

all of `countrycode`'s currency options...

```r
library(countrycode)

country = c("USA", "Canada", "UK", "Switzerland", "USA", "Sweden", "Switzerland", "Canada")

countrycode(country, "country.name", "iso4217c")
# [1] "USD" "CAD" "GBP" "CHF" "USD" "SEK" "CHF" "CAD"

countrycode(country, "country.name", "iso4217n")
# [1] 840 124 826 756 840 752 756 124

countrycode(country, "country.name", "currency")
# [1] "US Dollar"       "Canadian Dollar" "Pound Sterling"  "Swiss Franc"    
# [5] "US Dollar"       "Swedish Krona"   "Swiss Franc"     "Canadian Dollar"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion, but the previous solution is more straight to the point

Comment: can you maybe remove the part in your question that says the countrycode package does not convert to currency names to avoid confusing others?

Comment: Appreciate the coutrycode option but would be very helpful if one could use currency as origin.

Comment: @okost if so, what would `countrycode(“Euro”, “currency_name”, “country.name”)` return?

Comment: @CJYetman Error in countrycode("Euro", "currency_name", "country.name") : 
  Origin code not supported by countrycode or present in the user-supplied custom_dict.

Comment: Obv there are workarounds (see below if anyone cares) but seems like such a trivial ask that one could include it in the source code imo.
  fx <- data.frame(fx = countrycode::codelist$currency,
                   fxcode = countrycode::codelist$iso4217c)
  fx <- fx[!is.na(fx$fx),]
  fx <- fx[!duplicated(fx),]

Comment: It was a hypothetical/rhetorical  question, as in if currency was allowed, what would you expect/desire the result to be… with the intent of making it more clear why that is not allowed, because “Euro” would match numerous countries. If you use your own custom dictionary, whatever you want is totally achievable already, you would just have to make your own decision about what you want to match origins that match to multiple destinations to resolve to. Since it’s not clear to me how to make that decision universally for people, I don’t see how it fits in the pkg.

Comment: If you have a clear idea of how to do that, I encourage you to submit an issue at the countrycode GitHub page, which will be easier to use and likely be more fruitful than a StackOverflow comment thread. https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/countrycode